# Can the app extract data from marketing cloud using API, even when customer has logged out (using subdomain and api endpoints)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Let's say some customer installs the app from appExchange to his marketing cloud, and using outh2 authentication flow, app can get his subdomain and other api endpoints. 
Now, Can the app extract data from marketing cloud to some external location like AWS or Heroku even after he logs out of his account?

Comment: If the question is with view point of Marketing cloud, then answer is Yes. The REST APIs just need the CLIENT-ID and CLIENT-SECRETE and a valid end point.

Comment: So, it will be only one time authentication then app can extract data at anytime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When getting an access token, you will need to request the offline scope.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-app.htm

Doing so will return a refresh token in the response, which you can store and use to get a new access token at a later date/time without a user signed in. This will allow you to run background processes.

Comment: So background process can run till we have refresh token lifetime. If the lifetime expires customer has to authenticate again. Am I correct?